# Unable to scroll to the bottom of WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I am using visual studio 2012 for this. Basically I have a WinForm that I want to expand.

Inside the form designer, I am able to see that my form has a scroll bar, but when I compile the program, the scroll bar does not appear. The controls that are beyond my screen size are clipped off, as opposed to having a scrollbar.

Are there any settings that I have missed out? Currently I set my AutoScroll = true.

Answer (score 3):

Scrollbars show up when a parent control has the `AutoScroll` set to true and a child control has a `MinimumSize` such that the client area of the child control is larger than the client area of the parent control.

E.g.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var sampleForm = new Form() { AutoScroll = true };

    Panel panel = new Panel() { BackColor = Color.Red, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink, AutoSize = true };
    Button btn = new Button { Text = "Toggle MinSize", AutoSize = true };
    panel.Controls.Add(btn);

    btn.Click += delegate {
        if (panel.MinimumSize == Size.Empty)
            panel.MinimumSize = new Size(600,600);
        else
            panel.MinimumSize = Size.Empty;
    };

    sampleForm.Controls.Add(panel);
    Application.Run(sampleForm);
}
```

If your child panel correctly calculates its preferred size, then you can override the `MinimumSize` property and return the `PreferredSize`.

Answer (score 1):

AutoScroll = true is enough to display scroll on form no other setting is required.

just try other thing add panel in form and set panels AutoScroll = true and then add control to it and check that scroll is working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the properties of the controls within the container for which you want autoscroll to work.  One possibility is that you set one or more of those controls Anchor property to Right or something, which can reverse the autoscroll setting behind the scenes to effectively turn it off. Also check the RightToLeft property of the container, and try setting that to the default "no"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set `Dock.Fill` i.e. Dock property to Fill
Set property **AutoScroll = true , AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly** ,you can also do this by adding a panel to the form and set panel AutoScroll = true.
compare your issue with example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll(v=vs.110).aspx)